# Browse verify this field blank

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good afternoon, I have a doubt.
I have a div with two input button and a div, to send data via $ ajax More event just prior to sending $ ajax, I have to validate these two field Check that this blank. Most do not know how to do it for him not enable the sending if it receives false answer;

Example of my code,

```
<div id="fields">
     <input type="text" name="u" class="input" id="u" size="42" />
     <input type="text" name="s" class="input" id="s" size="10" />
</div>
     <input type="submit" class="bt" value="my user" />
```

jquery of my code,

```
 $("input.bt").click(function() {

      var da = $("#u").val();
      var dc = $("#s").val();

      //check this fields blank.
      //Resport true
      //$ ajax send data below ..

    $.ajax({
    ...POST...   
});
```

I would be very grateful for the help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To checkout if either of the values are blank, you can do:

```
if(da.length == 0 || dc.length == 0){
  //invalid input
} else {
  // do POST request
}
```

If you want to add an error label for `#s`, you can do the following in jQuery:

```
$('#s').after('<Label>Error: Field</label>');
```

Comment: Strict equality tests may not work if the browser returns a null instead of an empty string for "empty" values.

Comment: thanks, do you know how to return the error with a white <label> Field </ label> input side that is blank? Example: <input type="text" name="s" class="input" id="s" size="10" /><label>Erro: Field </ label>

Comment: You should use the jquery plugin validate http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/